# android enable and disable button in registration screen

Tags: android, button

I created registration screen i want to disable submit button and it should enable only when all the fields get correct input, bellow i added list of text fields these fields must get correct input and submit button must enable.

```
protected boolean validateData() {

    if (email.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        email.setError("Email-ID/Registered Number can not be empty!");
        return false;
    } else if (!(email.getText().toString().trim().contains("@"))
            && email.getText().toString().trim().length() < 10) {
        email.setError("Email/Registered Number not valid!");
        return false;
    } else if (!(email.getText().toString().trim().contains("."))
            && email.getText().toString().trim().length() < 10) {
        email.setError("Email/Registered Number not valid!");
        return false;
    }

    else if (!(email.getText().toString().trim().contains("@"))
            && !(email.getText().toString().trim().contains("."))
            && email.getText().toString().trim().length() > 10) {
        email.setError("Email/Registered Number not valid!");
        return false;
    }

    else if (email.getText().toString().trim().contains("@")
            || email.getText().toString().trim().contains(".")) {
        if (!WebServiceSingleTon.getInstance().isEmailValid(
                email.getText().toString().trim())) {
            email.setError("Email is not valid!");
            return false;
        } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            password.setError("password can not be empty!");
            return false;
        } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
            password.setError("Your password need to have minimum 6 characters!");
            return false;
        } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() > 20) {
            password.setError("Your password need to have maximum 20 characters!");
            return false;
        }
    } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        password.setError("password can not be empty!");
        return false;
    } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
        password.setError("Your password need to have minimum 6 characters!");
        return false;
    } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() > 20) {
        password.setError("Your password need to have maximum 20 characters!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question ? Also one more thing : instead of this email.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 use : email.getText().toString().trim().isEmtpy() (This would tell you if the text field is empty or not)

Answer (score 0):

to make a button "disabled" You'll need to set it's `android:clickable` property to false. Then, set a custom background on it that changes its background to gray (or however you want to it look while its disabled). Then after you call that validateData() function you can check to see if you should change the background of the button to be "enabled"